# Cómo calcular n rangos en data frame

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo una base en la que poseo el momento del día (en segundos) en que un auto pasó por cierto lugar. Debo juntar los que pasaron en el mismo intervalo de 5 minutos y calcular la velocidad instantánea promedio que posee ese intervalo, es decir los que pasaron entre los primeros 300 s, entre 301 y 600s, 601 y 900...86101 y 86400. Claramente no puedo aplicar un ifelse tantas veces. Mi idea era asignar un número a cada rango y luego hacer el cálculo agrupando por ese número. Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
Tiempo  Velocidad
9376    76
12503   118
20797   84
25779   120
25861   95
27109   119
35452   86
35841   108
39701   90
46774   79
47929   114
53095   109
55775   98
58846   118
59669   70
67508   92
72297   106
74095   103
82642   97
```

Answer (score 0):

El truco es poder saber a que número de `intervalo` corresponde cada `Tiempo`. La forma más sencilla es hacer un poco de aritmética: `floor((Tiempo-1)/300)+1` y luego con `tidyverse`, agrupamos y sumarizamos la media de cada uno de estos intervalos:

```
library("tidyverse")

df %>% 
  mutate(intervalo = floor((Tiempo-1)/300)+1) %>% 
  group_by(intervalo) %>% 
  summarize(promedio_velocidad=mean(Velocidad))
```